Happy 2025 to all!
Place 13 consecutive integers, one of them 2025, in the empty circles of this figure so that the four numbers in any of the seven straights lines add up to the same constant. Do so in such a way that the number in the apex is as small as possible.


When doing seasonal clickbait-y new year things, it's important to embed the year number in the actual puzzle somehow. Cramming it in as an arbitrary constant with absolutely no effect on the solution doesn't quite cut it.
